# Looking for working example of WP7 PhoneGap Facebook plugin for signin button

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, cordova

I've tried all the code at https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect
that is recommended by the phonegap community, but i keep running into errors trying to get it to work.

As you can see I'm using cordova 1.6.0 which maybe the problem?

i've added the script files to in my html page

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.6.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js">/script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="facebook_js_sdk.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="ChildBrowser.js"></script>
```

And I've added the ChildBrowserCommand.cs into the plugins directory.

I then added this to device ready listener with my authentic app id (the real id not shown here)

```
      document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
      // once the device ready event fires, you can safely do your thing! -jm
      function onDeviceReady() {
          //document.getElementById("welcomeMsg").innerHTML += "Cordova is ready! version=" + window.device.cordova;
          console.log("onDeviceReady. You should see this message in Visual Studio's output window.");



          //fb connect sign in
          try {
              //alert('Device is ready! Make sure you set your app_id below this alert.');
              console.log('Device is ready! Make sure you set your app_id below this alert.');

              FB.Cookie.setEnabled(true); // this seems to be duplicate to 'cookie: true' below, but it is IMPORTANT due to FB implementation logic.

              FB.init({ appId: "311961255484993", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, cookie: true });

              login();
          } catch (e) {
              //alert(e);
              console.log("Init error: " + e);
          }
      };

      function login() {
          FB.login(
                function (response) {
                    if (response.session) {
                        console.log('logged in');
                    } else {
                        console.log('not logged in');
                    }
                },
                { scope: 'email, read_stream, read_friendlists' }
            );
            }
```

The error i get is

Unable to locate command :: org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect

Any help?

EDIT: I also realize it's coming from cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js in here but not sure why?

```
    cordova.exec(function () {
        var authResponse = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cdv_fb_session') || '{"expiresIn":0}');
        if (authResponse && authResponse.expirationTime) {
            var nowTime = (new Date()).getTime();
            if (authResponse.expirationTime > nowTime) {
                // Update expires in information
                updatedExpiresIn = Math.floor((authResponse.expirationTime - nowTime) / 1000);
                authResponse.expiresIn = updatedExpiresIn;

                localStorage.setItem('cdv_fb_session', JSON.stringify(authResponse));
                FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(authResponse, 'connected');
            }
        }
        console.log('Cordova Facebook Connect plugin initialized successfully.');
    }, (fail ? fail : null), 'org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect', 'init', [apiKey]);
},
```